# Modifing data while using iterrows() does not work

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using iterrows() to work my way through a dataframe. Using a for loop and  nested if statements I'm able to identify the cells I want to change.
I used a print statement to verifiy I'm able to change the data but when I print out the dataframe the information is unchanged. I was able to do this on a smaller dataframe. Any ideas?

My original this was my code that worked:

```
data.loc[(data.ID.isin([10,45])) & (data.source.notnull()), 'ID'] = 50
```

But I need to add this:

```
data.loc[(data.ID.isin([23,45])) & (data.source.notnull()), 'ID'] = 60
```

This worked for me as a test
The DataFrame did change with this logic:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_wings': [10, 23, 32, 45],
                   'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
                  index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])
for x,y in data.iterrows():
    if y['num_wings'] in [10,45]:
        y['num_wings'] = 50
        print(x,y)
```

This is basically what I'm trying to do:
I can changed the data using this logic but it doesn't seem to change the actual DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
...
...
for x,y in data.iterrows():
    if y['ID'] in [10,45]:
        if y['source'] == 0:
            if y['username'] == 'bill':
                y['IDs'] = 50
                print(x,y) #print the results to confirmed it worked, it did/
                          # however, dataframe is unchanged
```

This worked for me
The DataFrame did change with this logic:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_wings': [10, 23, 32, 45],
                   'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
                  index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])
for x,y in data.iterrows():
    if y['num_wings'] in [10,45]:
        y['num_wings'] = 50
        print(x,y)
```

I feel confident that I can make the changes I want but I need to appy it to the DataFrame.

Comment: Most of the time, iteration using `iterrows` is not the best way to go with `pandas`. You should have a look to [indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) and [vectorization](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#iteration) (see first warning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesn't work because: ([source](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html))

> Depending on the data types, the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no effect.

To write to it, you can try to see if `at` works, i.e.,

```
for x,y in data.iterrows():
    if y['num_wings'] in [10,45]:
        data.at[x, 'num_wings'] = 50
```

Just modifying something while you're iterating over it is not recommended. But I think it should be OK in your case.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, you're trying to conditionally update the value of the num_wings column? If so, here you go. You need to use the .loc method to update values in a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_wings': [10, 23, 32, 45],
                   'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
                  index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])

data.loc[data['num_wings'].isin([10,45]),'num_wings'] = 50

data

        num_legs  num_specimen_seen  num_wings
falcon         2                 10         50
dog            4                  2         23
spider         8                  1         32
fish           0                  8         50
```